# Scrapy spider will not crawl on start urls

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am brand new to scrappy and have worked my way through the tutorial and am trying to figure out how to implement what I have learned so far to complete a seemingly basic task. I know very little python so far and am using this as a learning experience, so if I ask a simple question, I apologize.

My goal for this program is to follow this link http://ucmwww.dnr.state.la.us/ucmsearch/FindDocuments.aspx?idx=xwellserialnumber&val=971683 and to extract the well serial number to a csv file. Eventually I want to run this spider on several thousand different well files and retrieve specific data. However, I am starting with the basics first.

Right now the spider doesnt crawl on any web page that I enter. There are no errors listed in the code when I run it, it just states that 0 pages were crawled. I cant quite figure out what I am doing wrong. I am positive the start url is ok as I have checked it out. Do I need a specific type of spider to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class Sonrisdataaccess(Spider):
  name = "serial"
  allowed_domains = ["sonris.com"]
  start_urls = [
      "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=972498"]


 def parse(self, response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]')

    for question in questions:
        item = SonrisdataaccessItem()
        item['serial'] = question.xpath ('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Thank you for any help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is the indentation of your code the same as you posted here? If yes then it is normal that your spider does not work. If not please edit your question and fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I do not understand what you are doing in your for loop because if you have a selector you do not get the whole HTML again to select it...

Nevertheless, the interesting part is that the browser represents the table way different than it is downloaded with Scrapy. If you look at the response in your `parse` method you will see that there is no `tbody` element in the first `table`. This is why your selection does not return anything.

So to get the first serial number (as it is in your XPath) change your parse function to this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = SonrisdataaccessItem()
    item['serial'] = response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

For later changes you may have to alter the XPath expression to get more data.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have deleted the for loop and have edited my parse language to your suggestion, but the code still will not download anything. As I mentioned in my intitial question, I am very new at this and am likely to add in/have missing obvious things.

Comment: I also edited my code in my question to better reflect the indentations.

Comment: OK, if the indentation is now what you have then it is understandable that your parse method does not print anything: the `parse` method should belong to the `Sonrisdataaccess` class: one indentation level to the right, the same as `name` or `start_urls`.

Comment: I tried this and it still gives me a 0 crawled result

Comment: In this case I have no idea. A screenshot of your code would be eventually nice to see and if the `parse` method gets called or not (with a `print response.url` as the first statement in the method). However this would imho extend the options of StackOverflow a bit.

Comment: after more toying with the code, you were indeed correct. I had forgotten to save the item file and when the spider was going to call the item file, it wasnt calling anything. Rookie mistake I know. Thanks again for your help and I am sorry for any frusteration I caused you

Comment: Don't worry, there was no frustration. And thanks for the update it is good to know the reason for the problem.